# jQuery addClass chaining

Tags: jquery, addclass, chaining

I use the following code to show hide elements in a list. They work just fine when i call the functions the first time, second time arround the class hidden-person doesn;t get added anymore. I cannot understand why

Using jquery effects is not an option i have so many elements it just blocks the page. I have those classes to add fadeout effect with css animations

http://jsfiddle.net/deerua/JB39j/9/

See the example.. switch through the different states, it will not work to go in the same state twice because it fails to add the class hidden-person the second time around :/

Comment: Please put your HTML! Can you provide an working eg. on jsfiddle.net? Also mention when do you call this functions.

Comment: try with [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JB39j/ html here, i call these function on click events on a select element.

Comment: you have used `$deputat`, `senator` in your jQuery code, please provide the information about this variable. How are you selecting this. we cannot do each thing to make your fiddle working as per your question.

Comment: Your code must work like in this http://jsfiddle.net/deerua/JB39j/9/ sample?

Comment: @Murtaza have you even read my fiddle ? the variables are declared there

Comment: @deerua no. if you toggle through those states twice they stop working properly

Answer (score -1):

```
    $senator.removeClass('hide-person hidden-person');
    $deputy.addClass('hide-person');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $deputy.addClass('hidden-person');
    }, 1000);
```

I fixed it with a setTimeout(). Still curious why the first code i wrote doesn't work :/